# Run windows command with special symbols in Python

Tags: python, windows

I need to run windows commands from Python 3,
Commands contains slashes, dots, brackets, etc.:

```
.\TFSSecurity.exe /gc vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/$PROJECT_ID $GROUP_NAME $GROUP_DESCRIPTION /collection:$ORGANIZATION

.\TFSSecurity.exe /imx "[$PROJECT_NAME]\$GROUP_NAME" /collection:$ORGANIZATION
```

How could it be wrapped in Python correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"""
Run TFSSecurity from Python
"""

import subprocess
import argparse

PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()

PARSER.add_argument("--organization", type=str, required=True)
PARSER.add_argument("--projectId", type=str, required=True)

ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()

CMD = [
    "C:\\Program Files\\Azure DevOps Server 2019\\Tools\\TFSSecurity.exe",
    "/g",
    f"vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/{ARGS.projectId}",
    f"/collection:{ARGS.organization}",
]

CLI_OUTPUT = subprocess.run(
    CMD, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True
).stdout.decode("utf-8")

print(f"[INFO] CLI_OUTPUT: {CLI_OUTPUT}")
```